# How to add LinkServer to MySQL on SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linked-server

I am trying to add a linked server on SQL Server to MySQL Server. Note SQL Server is install on a different machine with a different domain name.

So Server "10.0.1.1" old_domain.com "SQL Server" and the second server is "10.0.1.2" new_domain.com MySQL Server.

I have added a ODBC Data Source on server "10.0.1.1" and tested the connection no problem.

Then I opened Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and navegared to 
SQLSERVER>Server Object>Linked Servers

then I got to the wizard to add linked server and I filled it like so
Linked Server: "MySQLNewServer"
I selected "Other data source"
Providor "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC"
Product name "Connection to MySQL"
Data source "MySQL" the same name at the Data Source that was added in the first step.
On the security tab I selected "Be made using this security Context" and I put SQL Server user name and SQL Server password then I hit "Ok"

Note: I followed the instruction on this link
http://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/link-mysql-to-ms-sql-server2008/

but I get this error:

OLE DB Providor "MSDASQL" for linked Server "MySQLNewServer" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver] Can't connect to MySQL server on 10.0.1.1 (10055) Microsoft SQL Server Error: 7303.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? How can I get these 2 server to communicate?

Thanks

Comment: How are you authenticating against MySQL?  Have you checked that the credentials you're passing are correct?

Comment: ps. this one may be more appropriate for http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: How would I check authentications against MySQL? when I added the ODBC Source i did a test and it worked.

Comment: When you created the ODBC Data Source, did you save credentials there.  When creating the linked server, did you include credentials in your connection string?  On the security tab, what security context did you choose?

Comment: I save the user/password when created the ODBC and I tried to add a string but did not work. Same error. this is the string DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=10.0.1.2;PORT=3306;DATABASE=repltest; USER=root;PASSWORD=password;OPTION=3;

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble with this topic, there is a nuance between 32 and 64 bit ODBC configurations.  The following worked.

1. Create a system DSN using MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver, set the
   schema or DB to be accessed
2. Create a new linked server in SSMS
3. Select Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC
4. Enter the System DSN name for the Product name
5. Enter the system DSN name for the Data source
6. Enter a provider string `DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.5.1 Driver};`
7. Under security, select Be made using this security context, enter
   the appropriate user id and password

Comment: I found another provider string of `DRIVER=(MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver);SERVER=localhost;PORT=3306;DATABASE=mantisbt; USER=user;PASSWORD=password;OPTION=3;` on this site [www.thebuttonfactory.nl](http://www.thebuttonfactory.nl/code/creating-a-linked-server-mysql-to-mssqlquery-the-mysql-database-without-openquery-function/)